# When iterating through TOC and erasing using ArcPy parameters are not valid?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to Iterate through my TOC and "Erase" part of the feature layers by using a predefined mask. However I keep getting an error that tells me the "Mask" is either not supported, or does not exist. I can say that the feature exists and that the format is supported, as it does work when I use "Erase" within ArcMap itself. Hence it must be something in my code.

I am a beginner at best when it comes to Arcpy/Python.

I have checked the path and this is correct.

Code:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Export = r"G:\\zn\\NM\\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\Export_{}\\Mask".format(Project_number, Project_number)
Import = r"G:\zn\NM\GGB\Applicaties-Admin\Kerngis\ExpImp\{}\Import_{}\Erased".format(Project_number, Project_number)


mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  # Uses your currently open MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers

    arcpy.Erase_analysis (lyr, Export, Import)
```

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `r` before the path because you already escaped the backslash using `\\\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add .gdb inside the path names. This is the current working code:

```
import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Export = "G:\\zn\\NM\\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\Export_{}.gdb\\Mask".format(Project_number, Project_number)
Import = "G:\\zn\\NM\GGB\\Applicaties-Admin\\Kerngis\\ExpImp\\{}\\Import_{}.gdb\\Erased".format(Project_number, Project_number)


mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  # Uses your currently open MXD
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, ''): # Loop through dataframes
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, '', df): # Loop through layers
        # Any tools you want to run on each layer go here

        arcpy.Erase_analysis (lyr, Export, Import)
```